# Request entity too large

Tags: apache-2.4, magento, php7

I'm saving product in Magento admin, but it presents the following error:

> Request Entity Too Large The requested resource
>   /admin/system_config/save/section/carriers/key/gs12323230599f2ce25da01b8b27cb596b06974f011331a/
>   does not allow request data with POST requests, or the amount of data
>   provided in the request exceeds the capacity limit.

We have Apache and PHP settings are:

memory_limit = 768M

post_max_size = 128M

max_input_vars = 10000

Any ideas what settings to tinker?

Comment: What you try to do?

Comment: Trying to save a product in admin or save configurations of certain extension. Both present this error.

Comment: This error is most likely generated by Magento, so you need to look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause of this was SSLRenegBufferSize. Increasing that value fixed this issue.